# error while declaring enum within an interface

Tags: java, enums, interface

The idea is to create an interface consiting of an enum that would hold county codes so I can use it later as a value for a variable in objects.

It supposed to be something like:

```
public interface CountrCodes {

  public enum Countries { france(FR), germany(D), spain(ES), portugal(PT)};

}
```

But it IDE (Eclipse) is arguing with me that:

```
> Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
>   - 'enum' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source level 1.5       on
>   - enum cannot be resolved to a type
>   - PT cannot be resolved to a variable
>   - ES cannot be resolved to a variable
>   - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
>   - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
>   - D cannot be resolved to a variable
>   - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration
>   - F cannot be resolved to a variable
```

It's my irst time with enums and I am confused as I thought it was absolutely legal and correct to use enum within an interface. How can I make it work?

Comment: Are you sure you have your Java version set? It looks like you may be defaulting to 1.4.

Comment: Well, FR, D, ES and PT are not defined anywhere. I guess you want `france("FR")`. But even then, your enum would need a constructor accepting a String.

Comment: I recommend looking at the `Planet` example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: @JBNizet That's not the error, though, and `enum cannot be resolved to a type` combined with the previous warning suggests that the compiler isn't treating `enum` as a keyword.

Comment: @chrylis I agree. I upvoted your comment BTW. Also, to the OP, the enum should be named Country, not Countries. France is a country, not a countries.

Comment: You should show the whole code

Comment: Also a non programming related error: The correct alpha 2 country code for germany would be "DE", not "D".

Comment: @911DidBush he's probably using the codes shown on car number plates.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou then he would also have to use "F" for France, "E" for Spain and "P" for Portugal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to say when, exactly, it became possible for interface declarations to have nested members, but nested members are possible since at least Java 7.

If you define an interface for which a set of constants are available for use primarily with that interface, then it may be convenient to nest the constants as an enum class within the interface.  This is a perfectly acceptable use case for interfaces.  Consider your own code:

```
public interface CountryCodes {

    public enum Countries { france(FR), germany(D), spain(ES), portugal(PT)};

}
```

It is apparent that you wish to nest the enum class `Countries` within the interface `CountryCodes` (since a single enum constant is a single thing, I suggest not using the plural for the enum class name, eg. `Country.SPAIN` rather than `Countries.SPAIN`; enum constants should be named in all capitals as well by convention).

What is different in your declaration, however, is that you clearly wish to associate data with the constants.  Therefore, your enum class requires an instance field and a constructor:

```
public interface CountryCodes {

    public static enum Country {
        FRANCE("FR"),
        GERMANY("DE"),
        SPAIN("ES"),
        PORTUGAL("PT");

        private final String e_countryId;

        private Country(String c) {
            this.e_countryId = c;
        }
    }
    :
    :
}
```

The designation `static` in the enum class declaration is unnecessary .  I like to include it to make it clear that the enum is a nested member.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the outer interface to accomplish what you are attempting to accomplish. Define the enum in its own file (Countries.java):

```
public enum Countries {
    FRANCE("FR"), GERMANY("D")

    private Countries(code) {
        this.countryCode = code;
    }

    private String countryCode

}
```

Should get you what you need, though as others have suggested, this is not a terribly useful enum.

Comment: Good advice, though I'm not upvoting as it's not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: Good point. I suppose it pained me to actually answer the question as asked, so I suggested this instead.

Comment: If it was up to me I would do it this way, the thing is that I have to declare it within an interface. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to define the enum in its own file (see rmlan answer).

This is what your looking for:

```
public interface CountrCodes {

  public enum Countries { FRANCE, GERMANY, SPAIN, PORTUGAL};

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do, is called an inner enum. A enum which is inside a class, nothing fancy, and nothing complex. Totally legal. Also commons as inner classes. But in this case, it is an enum.

An enum is another kind of object, like classes, but they have some other properties. For example, enum are thread safe and they are serializable.

You particular example has no issues. It doesn't compiles, because the compiler can not resolve FR, D, ES and PT. If I remove those country codes, it compiles using Java 8.

For more references, take a look here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: So looks like in my case it's simply a matter of an older version of Java. :( At least I know how to solve it. Thanks.